# Dead battery is replaced and recognized on MacBook Pro – processor speed is still cut

Tags: performance, processor

Just replaced dead battery on MacBook Pro Late 2011, and it is seen by OS (el Captain) and charging OK.

[image]

Though, processor speed is still being cut and ticks only at 0.8 ghz and Apple Hardware test shows 4xxx error with the battery.

[image]

Did reset to all that possible, any ideas how to make Macbook see battery on a hardware level?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved by using an original battery.